# PostgreSQL columns in table being included in more than one index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am currently looking at adding indexes to my PostgreSQL database in development. The database is primarily a customer database, which will house around 5 million customer records in the Customer table, and all other tables are children of Customer, and may contain one or more records that associate back to a customer.

Most operations will be looking up a single customer, or updating a single customer, or adding a single customer.

Now for my part, I have appropriate primary keys on the customer and other tables, so I have an index there. I've also read that an index on the foreign key column in child tables is good practice. So I've come up with the below:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_contact ON contact_information (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_address ON address (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_mkpref ON marketing_preferences (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_content ON content_type_preferences (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_cards ON external_cards (customer_internal_id);
```

This should help for the query to look up a customer with the joins taking place by customer_internal_id. When reviewing all the queries my software makes, I came up with these general query types.

Contact Information

- Contact Information - where contact type = and contact value =
- Contact Information - where contact type =

Customer

- Customer - where first namd and last name.
- Customer - where first name and last name and DOB

External Cards

- External cards - WHERE card number =
- External cards - WHERE card number = AND card status =

My question is, let's take Contact Information queries, we most often look up contact details by either contact type and contact value, or just contact type. As contact type appears in both where clauses, do I just create

a) Single column indexes on each?
c) One multi-column index containing contact type and contact value, then a single column index containing contact type?

Example query to obtain customer Id from card number:

```
SELECT e.customer_internal_id

FROM external_cards AS e

WHERE e.card_number = @__request_CustomerSearchParameters_CardNumber_0
```

Example query to obtain customer by Id:

```
SELECT c.customer_internal_id, c.business_partner_id, c.created_date, c.customer_type, c.date_of_birth, c.first_name, c.gender, c.home_store_id, c.home_store_updated, c.last_name, c.loyalty_db_id, c.mca_id, c.status, c.status_reason, c.store_joined, c.title, c.updated_by, c.updated_date, c.updating_store, c0.contact_internal_id, c0.contact_type, c0.contact_value, c0.created_date, c0.customer_internal_id, c0.updated_by, c0.updated_date, c0.updating_store, c0.validated, a.address_internal_id, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_type, a.address_undeliverable, a.address_validated, a.country, a.created_date, a.customer_internal_id, a.postcode, a.region, a.suburb, a.updated_by, a.updated_date, a.updating_store, m.customer_internal_id, m.channel_id, m.created_date, m.opt_in, m.updated_by, m.updated_date, m.updating_store, m.valid_from_date, c1.customer_internal_id, c1.channel_id, c1.type_id, c1.created_date, c1.opt_in, c1.updated_by, c1.updated_date, c1.updating_store, c1.valid_from_date, e.customer_internal_id, e.card_number, e.card_design, e.card_status, e.card_type, e.created_date, e.updated_by, e.updated_date, e.updating_store

FROM customer AS c

LEFT JOIN contact_information AS c0 ON c.customer_internal_id = c0.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN address AS a ON c.customer_internal_id = a.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN marketing_preferences AS m ON c.customer_internal_id = m.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN content_type_preferences AS c1 ON c.customer_internal_id = c1.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN external_cards AS e ON c.customer_internal_id = e.customer_internal_id

WHERE c.customer_internal_id IN ('322e612b-89e7-4c1e-bdc5-5ec3e42adae8')

ORDER BY c.customer_internal_id, c0.contact_internal_id, c0.contact_type, a.address_internal_id, m.customer_internal_id, m.channel_id, c1.customer_internal_id, c1.channel_id, c1.type_id, e.customer_internal_id, e.card_number
```

I can't currently access the EXPLAIN output, but will attempt to gather and update here.

Comment: We need to at least see the actual queries you will be running.  Speculating without this information may lead to suboptimal/wrong indices being added.  Ideally, the explain plans would help too.

Comment: I've added a couple of example queries, can't get the EXPLAIN plans at the moment. Apologies, will gather more information when I can. I wasn't sure if there was a general consensus around what to do when your where clauses are different but contain overlap columns.

Comment: In general, each query might require a separate index.  But, you should check each query to see whether or not its running time sans-index might already be acceptable to you.  Also, not all queries would be run with the same frequency, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, a two-column index on contact type and contact value (in this order!) would be the best fit. It can also be used for `WHERE` conditions on contact type alone.

Note that an `IN (...)` condition is not the same as an `=` condition, unless the list has only a single element.

The queries you show exhibit an anti-pattern: querying one table, then querying another table with the results found in the first query. This is more efficiently done with a join of the tables.

Comment: Thanks. The anti-pattern is what has driven another question I've posted on SO, to avoid that very condition (i'm using EF Core, so it's not as simple as just writing the query, I need to know how to get EF Core to generate it).